# PythonでJsonファイルのように、リスト型に辞書型を代入して使用したい。

Tags: python, python3

複数の辞書型を一つのリストで管理したいです。

```
{'itag': 18, 'mime_type': 'video/mp4', 'res': '360p', 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': 'avc1.42001E', 'acodec': 'mp4a.40.2', 'file_type': 'video'}
{'itag': 313, 'mime_type': 'video/webm', 'res': '2160p', 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': 'vp9', 'acodec': None, 'file_type': 'video'}
{'itag': 271, 'mime_type': 'video/webm', 'res': '1440p', 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': 'vp9', 'acodec': None, 'file_type': 'video'}　・・・続く
```

上記の値を下記のようにリストでまとめたいのですが、`リスト.append（辞書型）をfor 辞書型 in jsonファイルのように[辞書型,辞書型・・・]:`で追加してくとなぜかリストの中身が最後の辞書型の値に全て置き換わってしまいます。まさに下の通りです。おそらく仕様だと思うのですが、期待する動作にしたい場合どうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
[{'itag': 251, 'mime_type': 'audio/webm', 'res': None, 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': None, 'acodec': 'opus', 'file_type': 'audio'}, 
{'itag': 251, 'mime_type': 'audio/webm', 'res': None, 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': None, 'acodec': 'opus', 'file_type': 'audio'}, 
{'itag': 251, 'mime_type': 'audio/webm', 'res': None, 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': None, 'acodec': 'opus', 'file_type': 'audio'},
```

実際のコード

```
def makelist(self):
        alltag = self.alltag
        tags = {}
        tags_list = []
        audios = []
        videos = []

        for tag in alltag:
            
            tags['itag'] = tag.itag
            tags['mime_type'] = tag.mime_type
            tags['res'] = tag.resolution
            tags['abr'] = tag.abr
            tags['fps'] = tag.fps
            tags['vcodec'] = tag.video_codec
            tags['acodec'] = tag.audio_codec
            tags['file_type'] = tag.type
            
            tags_list.append(tags.copy())
            
        for tags in tags_list:
            if tags['file_type'] == 'audio':
                audios.append(tags.copy())# ここの.copyなしでやると上手く行かない。

            if tags['file_type'] == 'video':
                videos.append(tags.copy())
        
        self.audios = audios
        self.videos = videos
```

Comment: 実際のコードを追記してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

例えば下記のコードで全ての辞書型を入れられます。
`for 辞書型 in 複数辞書型:`のコードで`複数辞書型`の配列？に最後の辞書型を全て代入していたり、for文で取得した`辞書型`を使わずに複数辞書型の末尾のみ取得していたりしないでしょうか。
質問文を編集して実際のコードを追記していただけると、より明確な回答を得やすいかと思います。

```
d1 = {'itag': 18, 'mime_type': 'video/mp4', 'res': '360p', 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': 'avc1.42001E', 'acodec': 'mp4a.40.2', 'file_type': 'video'}
d2 = {'itag': 313, 'mime_type': 'video/webm', 'res': '2160p', 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': 'vp9', 'acodec': None, 'file_type': 'video'}
d3 = {'itag': 271, 'mime_type': 'video/webm', 'res': '1440p', 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': 'vp9', 'acodec': None, 'file_type': 'video'}
d4 = {'itag': 251, 'mime_type': 'audio/webm', 'res': None, 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': None, 'acodec': 'opus', 'file_type': 'audio'}
l = list()
for d in [d1, d2, d3, d4]:
    l.append(d)
print(l)

# [{'itag': 18, 'mime_type': 'video/mp4', 'res': '360p', 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': 'avc1.42001E', 'acodec': 'mp4a.40.2', 'file_type': 'video'}, {'itag': 313, 'mime_type': 'video/webm', 'res': '2160p', 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': 'vp9', 'acodec': None, 'file_type': 'video'}, {'itag': 271, 'mime_type': 'video/webm', 'res': '1440p', 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': 'vp9', 'acodec': None, 'file_type': 'video'}, {'itag': 251, 'mime_type': 'audio/webm', 'res': None, 'fps': 30, 'vcodec': None, 'acodec': 'opus', 'file_type': 'audio'}]
```

Comment: Githubに書かれた通りに書いたら動きました。https://gist.github.com/dogrunjp/9748789

Comment: `for in`で順番に取り出していると思うので末尾だけという事はないと思います。